# Check if string is in dictionary values, which are in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is to check if a string input is in dictionary, which values are in lists:

```
data_dict = {'mobile_panel': ["APP", "DTRAFFIC", "DSCHANGE", "SEARCH", "URL", "HTTP", "ALL"],
         'socio': ["-20.000 inh", "20.000-50.000 inh", "50.000-100.000 inh", "100.000 inh or more"]}
```

This is the dictionary. I want to create a functions for every key:value pair:

```
def mob_panel_in_list(string):
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if string in 'mobile_panel':
            return string
        else:
            return string + '_not_valid'
```

The next function to be for key - 'socio' and so on. The problem is that this function always returns the else statement. When I change 'mobile_panel' with value, I am getting the correct result, but this works only for the first key:value pair. How can I select the different keys and their values? I am missing something, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you post an expected output ?

Comment: @vlemaistre When the input is 'APP' the output will be the string, if its 'APPP' - APPP_not_valid

Comment: Check my answer, should give you that exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to create separate functions for each key in the dat_dict..

```
def mob_panel_in_list(panel):
   return panel if panel in data_dict['mobile_panel'] else panel+'_not_valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
def mob_panel_in_list(string):
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if string in key,value:
            return string
        else:
            return string + '_not_valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work for a single key at a time, and the values are always lists, you can do this:

```
def value_in_dict_list(key, string, mydict):
    if string in mydict[key]:
        return string
    else:
        return string + '_not_valid'

value_in_dict_list('mobile_panel', 'APPP', data_dict)
'APPP_not_valid'
```

If you want to do it for all keys at once and know which ones are which, again assuming values are always lists:

```
def value_in_dict_list(string, mydict):
    out_dict = {}
    for k, val in mydict.items():
        if string in val:
            out_dict[k] = string
        else:
            out_dict[k] = string + '_not_valid'
    return out_dict

value_in_dict_list('APPP', data_dict)
{'socio': 'APPP_not_valid', 
 'mobile_panel': 'APPP_not_valid'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_string_in_dict(string, data_dict, key):
    if string not in data_dict.get(key, []):
        return string + '_not_valid'
    return string
```

So you can have, for example:

```
>>> data_dict = {'mobile_panel': ["APP", "DTRAFFIC", "DSCHANGE", "SEARCH", "URL", "HTTP", "ALL"],
                 'socio': ["-20.000 inh", "20.000-50.000 inh", "50.000-100.000 inh", "100.000 inh or more"]}
>>> is_string_in_dict('APP', data_dict, 'mobile_panel')  
# 'APP' is in 'mobile_panel' list => return 'APP'
APP
>>> is_string_in_dict('APPP', data_dict, 'mobile_panel')  
# 'APPP' is not in 'mobile_panel' list => return 'APPP_not_valid'
APPP_not_valid
>>> is_string_in_dict('APP', data_dict, 'socio')  
# 'APP' is not in 'socio' list => return 'APPP_not_valid'
APP_not_valid
>>> is_string_in_dict('APP', data_dict, 'missing_key')  
# 'missing_key' is not a valid key => return 'APP_not_valid'
APP_not_valid
```